# Астериск->Cisco->PSTN. Как проиграть сообщения абоненту, а не шлюзу?

Tags: asterisk, sip, cisco

Имеем Asterisk 13.22.0 (FreePBX 14) в качестве АТС, Cisco2911 с модулями FXO в качестве шлюза в городскую телефонную сеть. Исходящая маршрутизация настроена, звонки ходят.

Поставлена задача проигрывать вызываемым абонентам сообщения о записи звонков. Реализована как добавление опции A(custom/DialogIsRecorded) к транку.

Проблема в том что проигрывание записи начинается после соединения Астериска с циской, а не с абонентом. В результате абонент в лучшем случае слышит часть проигрываемой фразы, в худшем (если поднял трубку совсем не сразу) - вообще ничего.

Мне кажется что ситуация выглядит примерно так: при исходящем звонке Астериск соединяется по протоколу SIP с циской, циска дает в ответ статус SIP 200 OK, и Астериск считает что соединение установлено и начинает проигрывать сообщение. Но Циска в этот момент только начинает набирать номер абонента, поэтому сообщение уходит в пустоту.

Как можно заставить Астериск проигрывать сообщение после поднятия трубки вызываемым абонентом, а не после соединения с шлюзом?

Answer (score 0):

Есть два варианта — правильный и дешёвый/нерабочий.

Правильный вариант — избавиться от FXO в принципе. Цифровая АТС и аналоговые линии — плохое сочетание.

Второй вариант — попробовать использовать TALK_DETECT, например, как [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556653/asterisk-silence-detection-on-connected-call).